# Updating and appending in Python loops

Tags: arrays, loops, python-2.7, dictionary, numpy

I'm a newbie to Python and I'm trying to develop a code that should perform K-Means clustering based on a predefined package called Pycluster. In the beginning I've been clustering using a fixed number of clusters (n=10 clusters) and the code was working fine. I tried to expand the code a little bit, so that instead of making 10 clusters only, I tried to make a loop that would increment the desired number of clusters from 2 up to 10 (or more). There started the problems because as I said, I'm totally new to Python. 
The code I developed can be traced as shown below. I realize that the error start regarding the code lines 33 to 49.
I really appreciate any help provided to make the code running.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Oct 21 13:53:40 2013

@author: Engin
"""


from Pycluster import *
import numpy as np


#Open the text file containing the stored smart meter data
d=np.loadtxt("120-RES-195-Normalized.txt", delimiter="\t", skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,49))


handle=open("120-RES-195-Normalized.txt")  
record = read(handle) #Store the smart meter data in an array called record.

cluster_results = np.ones((120, 11))
cluster_centroids=np.array([])
within_cluster_sum_of_squares=np.ones((1,11))
between_cluster_sum_of_squares=np.ones((1,11))
distance=[]

for n in range (1,11):
    cluster_results[:,n-1], within_cluster_sum_of_squares[:,n-1], optimal_solution_repetition = record.kcluster(nclusters=n, npass=10, method='a', dist='e')     #Performs the K-Means clustering using the defined parameters
    centroids, cmask = record.clustercentroids(cluster_results[:,n-1], method='a', transpose=0) #Calculates the cluster centroids
    cluster_centroids=np.append(cluster_centroids,centroids)

#The following routine stores the cluster numbers and the indices of the elements belonging to each
#cluster so that the Between Clusters Sum of Squares would be easily calculated. The results will also
#be easily visualised.
    from collections import defaultdict
    cluster_numbers_members = defaultdict(list)
    for i,item in enumerate(cluster_results[:,n-1]):
        cluster_numbers_members[item].append(i)
    cluster_numbers_members = {k:v for k,v in cluster_numbers_members.items() if len(v)>=1}
    cluster_members=cluster_numbers_members.values()
    cluster_numbers=cluster_numbers_members.keys()

    distance[:,n-1]=0
    between_cluster_sum_of_squares[:,n-1]=0
    for i in range(0,n):
        for k in range(0,n):
            distance[:,n-1] = record.clusterdistance(index1=cluster_members[i], index2=cluster_members[k], method='a', dist='e', transpose=0)
            between_cluster_sum_of_squares[:,n-1]=between_cluster_sum_of_squares[:,n-1]+distance[:,n-1]

    WCBCR = within_cluster_sum_of_squares/between_cluster_sum_of_squares
    print cluster_results[:,n-1]
    print within_cluster_sum_of_squares[:,n-1]

print cluster_centroids

#Arranging cluster centroids in (1X48) vector form
cluster_tuple=zip(*[iter(cluster_centroids)]*48)
cluster_array=numpy.array(list(cluster_tuple))
```

Comment: _" There started the problems because as I said, I'm totally new to Python."_ Please provide more detail. What kind of problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Hi @Kevin, I have updated the code because I had some errors in variable names. In an earlier version of the code, I used some other variable names, but had to rename them to make the code more clear and consistent. When I tried to run the current (updated) code, I keep getting the following error message:  distance[:,n-1]=0
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
[:,n-1]
```

with

```
[:n-1]  or [:(n-1)]  # same thing, use whatever you find easier to read
```

Comment: Hi @ExperimentsWithCode, I tried that but kept getting the following error code:  ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (120) into shape (0,11)

Comment: @user2470127 Does it give you a line number for that? I don't see where you are getting 'shape' from. Also, if you are able provide me some sample data in the correct input format, I can test some changes.

Comment: @user2470127 Ok, so I believe the shapes are matrixes. I believe the error you may be running into could be caused by whatever the second matrix is having no actual content. A matrix of shape(0,11) is '[]' which errors out when you try to do calculations between matrixes. I could not do any math between two matrixes of (120) and (0,11) without getting the following error:  'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (120) (0,11) ' If I made that second matrix (1,11) rather than (0,11) I was able to perform operations between them.

Comment: Hi @ExperimentsWithCode, Sorry for the late reply. Busy day and I just checked my email. Can you please tell how to send you a sample data in the correct format? I'm so thankful for the help you're providing.

Comment: @user2470127 All good. I know how that goes. I was able to create my own data file that appears to be working (using 4 active rows rather than your 120). I am running into the same error as you. I printed 'record.kcluster' and the results were '(array([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32), 1.7976931348623157e+308, 11)'. I tried multiplying/adding '[0,0,0,0] with np.ones((4, 11))' but I get 'operands could not be broadcast together' So I tried switching 'cluster_results = np.ones((4, 11))' to 'cluster_results = np.ones((11,4))' and switched [:n-1] with [n-1:]. Now it proceeds to the next line with error

Comment: So there is possibly something about how you have set up your arrays that is causing the issue. The new error I am getting now on line: 'centroids, cmask = record.clustercentroids(cluster_results[n-1:], method='a', transpose=0) #Calculates the cluster centroids' is 'ValueError: clusterid has incorrect rank (2 expected 1)'